# How can I read an XML file on python and make it into a text data for NLP work?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that I want to convert it into a corpus(text data) in python.
It looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE corpus SYSTEM "puns.dtd">

-<corpus lang="en" id="subtask2-heterographic">

-<text id="het_1">

<word id="het_1_1">'</word>

<word id="het_1_2">'</word>

<word id="het_1_3">I</word>

<word id="het_1_4">'</word>

<word id="het_1_5">m</word>

<word id="het_1_6">halfway</word>

<word id="het_1_7">up</word>

<word id="het_1_8">a</word>

<word id="het_1_9">mountain</word>

<word id="het_1_10">,</word>

<word id="het_1_11">'</word>

<word id="het_1_12">'</word>

<word id="het_1_13">Tom</word>

<word id="het_1_14">alleged</word>

<word id="het_1_15">.</word>

</text>
-<text id="het_2">

<word id="het_2_1">I</word>

<word id="het_2_2">'</word>

<word id="het_2_3">d</word>

<word id="het_2_4">like</word>

<word id="het_2_5">to</word>

<word id="het_2_6">be</word>

<word id="het_2_7">a</word>

<word id="het_2_8">Chinese</word>

<word id="het_2_9">laborer</word>

<word id="het_2_10">,</word>

<word id="het_2_11">said</word>

<word id="het_2_12">Tom</word>

<word id="het_2_13">coolly</word>

<word id="het_2_14">.</word>
</text>
</corpus>
```

Which way, or which library should I use to make this into

```
sample_corpus = [['When', 'Socrates', 'needed', 'to', 'buy', 'food', 'he', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'grocery', 'stoa', '.'],[
                 'Acupuncture', 'is', 'a', 'jab', 'well', 'done', '.']]
```

this kind of format? Will I have to do some parsing by myself or is there a library that does this for me? With the corpus, I will eventually be getting bigram frequency of the corpus.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the corpus you provided.

Comment: That's just the format I want.

Comment: It will help for them to align so it's (more) obvious how the mapping from the xml file to the list of lists should happen. Otherwise it looks like you want the words in the result to appear from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file is not formatted properly. Remove the '-' before any xml tags (e.g. text) and save it as a file and then try the code below. A list of all the unique words will be saved in the list variable words

```
import pprint as pp
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('XMLCorpus.xml')
words = []
for wordElement in root.iter('word'):
    words.append(wordElement.text)

pp.pprint (words)
```